# How does CMake know which version of Qt to use?

Tags: qt, cmake

I have been using Qt4 for a while successfully. I can use CMake commands such as `QT4_WRAP_CPP`, `QT4_WRAP_UI`, etc. Now I have installed Qt5, but for some reason Qt doesn't recognize my installation. I receive this error.

```
CMake Error at /example/project/dir/build_target.cmake:102 (QT5_WRAP_CPP):
  Unknown CMake command "QT5_WRAP_CPP".
```

How do I

- Check which versions of Qt are found by CMake?
- Specify the version of Qt that CMake should use?
- Ensure that Qt is properly installed?

Comment: What's your cmake version? Did you [read this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) , and set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH correctly? Can you try with a new most basic project and short .cmake and see if it goes wrong then, and if it does give us the file you're using to build?

Answer (score 5):

If you use `FindQt3` or `FindQt4` it will find you Qt 3 or 4. With `FindQt` it tries to find Qt 3 or 4 and you can specify the `DESIRED_QT_VERSION` (3 or 4). Currently with CMake 3.5 it does not find Qt 5.

For Qt 5, there are no longer specific find commands provided, you have to look for specific parts of Qt 5, line their widgets with `find_package(Qt5Widgets)`. The version is then stored in `Qt5Widgets_VERSION`.

See also the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

Why is this so complicated? In the past CMake tried to provide a find* module for every software it supported. The list of modules grew fast and with every new version of Boost, Qt, Gtk and so on the modules needed testing and often modifications. This system did not scale.
Now CMake prefers config files that are provided by the third-party softwares themselves. Until Qt4 CMake provided a find module. Beginning with Qt 5, Qt provides the config files.

Usually with CMake you don't check whether a library is installed correctly. With Autotools these checks where common but not with CMake. Probably these checks take some time and it's the user's responsibility to have working libraries.

Comment: Thank you for the background information and insight.